# Simplified base map in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, basemap

I am trying to make an online map with GeoServer.

I am making the map now in HTML with the OpenLayers library. I want to use a different base map because the default map from OpenLayers is more than I need.

I only want to see the countries, for example, not the roads and things like that.

Is this possible? And if so, how is this possible then?

Comment: Probably best done using a vector (or vector tile) layer.  There's a very basic one in the OpenLayers examples http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/vector-label-decluttering.html The country outlines are very approximate but you could improve the appearance by editing the styles.  For better quality you could use vector tiles, for example https://cloud.maptiler.com/tiles/v3/#0/0/0 (you will need to sign up for a free API key).  By setting styles (MapTiler has an editor) you can choose which features you want to show and how they are shown.